# Execute method inside signed console app from an unsigned assembly by Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, sign

First of all,

Sorry about my ignorance about .net and everything in general, I've been working for a long time with it but i'm still in process to learning, that's way i'm asking.

I'm learning about reflection and i was practicing when i tried the following:

i added an unsigned reference to an signed assembly and all ok ; the compiler said the reference hadn't a strong name (that's what i expected).

But when i used the `MethodInfo.Invoke(null, null)` to invoke the static method it worked perfectly.

I signed the project(just the console one) by the configuration tab page.

i don't understand, can someone explain me better

The question is:

If the assembly is not signed why works in a signed assembly when invoke by reflection.

Thanks,

My code

The code from the only class signed assembly(Console application) project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(
                @"path\ClassLibrary1.dll");

          var m= a.GetType("ClassLibrary1.ZZ");
          MethodInfo met = m.GetMethod("TroskisTroskis");
          met.Invoke(null,null);


           Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The code from the only class NON signed assembly project:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public  static class ZZ
    {
        public  static void TroskisTroskis()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand? It seems like you posted working code...!?

Comment: it musn't work, it's not signed

Comment: Not a duplicate question, but the right answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14859591/1081897)

Comment: Thanks, I understand this a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

A signed assembly can not reference a non-signed assembly, but it can late bind to one (load it).